# QML: Mimic GridView/ListView cacheBuffer with Grid

Tags: qt, gridview, qml

I have quite complex QML view which basically is a `GridView`, but default `GridView` is not used because it doesn't support sections.

For this reason I am using a combination of `Flickable`+`Grid`s and `Repeater` to populate multiple section headers + its grids under one scroll.

Now, as `cacheBuffer` is not available and we do have quite heavy visual delegates for the views + infinite model for the last section(which is fetched as user scrolls further) our **RAM consumption** is increasing like crazy when you continuously scrolling. My best guess yet is that **each instantiated QML delegate is being kept in memory basically forever**.

I'm looking for the solution where you mimic `GridView`'s `cacheBuffer` property and apply it for simple `Grid` and unload delegates that are far away from visible scroll area.

As for now, am thinking about using `Loader` to load each delegate and keep track of what items are in/close to visible scroll area so theirs `Loader`s can load/unload its content.

Would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: did you solve it? i want to see a simple map of what you 've done

Comment: @MahdiKhalili I used Loader for each delegate, then track how far each one is from current viewing position (contentX/contentY + width/height) and load/unload delegates accordingly (see Loader::source). Requires a lot of fine tuning to work good(used to compare my solution with how webrowsers are working on some large list of pictures(smoothness of scrolling and RAM usage)), but I'm quite happy with a result. Sorry, I can not share my code because of my agreement with a company I worked on while implementing this.